# Valums Ajax upload and File Uploader

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

On Valums github I've found two repositories of uploaders:

https://github.com/valums

The first one called Ajax upload and the second File uploader. On demo pages they are doing the same things for the first look, but there should be some differences?
I'm asking for an advice which library did you use and what the difference in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileUploader is the newer product that grew out of the original AJAX uploader which he keeps there for archival purposes. The FileUpload is much more robust and in newer browsers allows uploading entirely with XmlHttpRequest instead of needing the iFrame trick.

I have successfully integrated FileUploader into CodeIgniter as well as stand alone projects. Works very well.

Comment: FileUploader is now also dead, and even its successor FineUploader is no longer maintained.